# Как проверить в retrofit было ли соединение и запрос успешным?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

```
    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        cache(
            Cache(context.cacheDir, 500 * 1024 * 1024)
        )
        addInterceptor {
            val request: Request = it.request()

            if (true) {
                Log.d("GetIsConnectionSocket", "Подключение к серверу: ${it.call().execute().isSuccessful}")
                // Если есть подключение к серверу, используйте сетевой запрос
                request.newBuilder().apply {
                    header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 365)
                }.build()
                Log.d("GetStateCache", "Данные из кеша не используются")
            } else {
                Log.d("GetIsConnectionSocket", "Подключение к серверу: ${it.call().execute().isSuccessful}")
                // Если нет подключения, используйте запрос из кэша
                request.newBuilder().apply {
                    header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
                }.build()
                Log.d("GetStateCache", "Данные из кеша используются")

            }
            it.proceed(request)
        }

    }.build()
```

Comment: а где здесь ретрофит?

Comment: не добавил фрагмента кода с ретрофит, okHttpClient только. Он больше нужен

Comment: так рерофит может вам вернуть свой объект `Response`. и вот он как раз и может быть `Success` или `Error`. и если `Error` то вы там и текст ошибки найдете, и код ошибки и все все что вам надо. okhttp в ретрофите редко трогают (из моей практики, только чтобы через снифер к защищенным серверам запросы делать)

Comment: а как сделать запрос внутри OkHttpClient, если нужно проверить. Если isSuccessful равен true то данные берутся из сети, а если false то из кеша. Но Вылезает ошибка, `Could not locate call adapter for retrofit2.Response<ru.project.retrofitlearning.domain.models.ProductList>.`,

 `Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response<ru.project.retrofitlearning.domain.models.ProductList>`

Comment: ох... это хороший и отличный вопрос! суть заключаетяс в том, что у вас есть нейкий ответ от сервера, например объект класс `ApiResult`. и у вас есть участок кода, где вы с помощью ретрофит и с помощью `try-catch` или через `Response` пытаетесь получить ответ и проверить его. и вот этот кусок когда уже должен возвращать не просто ответ `ApiResult`, а что-то типа `Result<ApiResult>`. где у `Result` может быть 2 состояния `Success` и `Error`. лучше всего это делать с помощью котлиновских sealed-классов.

Comment: а т.к. как у вас еще есть класс, который обработает ответ от сети и в случае ошибка - возьмет данные из БД. а в случае успеха - сохранит данные в БД. то этом месте, вам можно будет сделать еще один класс `ResultCache<ApeResult>`, у которого кроме `Success` (данные есть, ошибки нет) и `Error` (ошибка есть, данных нет) будет еще одно состояние `Cashe` (данные есть, ошибка есть). таким образом вы точно будете знать, на слоях выше, откуда взялись данные (из сети, из кэша. либо же ошибка, когда ни в сети, ни в кэше данных нет)